# How to tail text from a specific control from an external program?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, automation, ui-automation

I have tried inspecting this window using **Inspect.exe** provided on **Windows' 8.1 Software Development Kit Testing Tools**. I couldn't seem to identify the control handle for this huge rich textbox like control. I could however get the control handle of the edit box below the textbox.  I was hoping I could talk directly to the control and use a library such as [WindowScrape](https://github.com/DataDink/WindowScrape) to get the text.

I believe the external program is created in VC++ . If that helps.

This is the window. I am trying to get text from that is boxed in red color. This is a chat window , messages come in every 5 to 10 seconds. This box scrolls automatically. I want to tail through the text and get the latest message.

**Is there any other way to accomplish this?**

[Tesseract](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) maybe, but I do not know where to start to monitor a specific position relative to the window. So that when I move the window it will still be able to monitor that window.

[image]

Comment: Not everything you see on screen is required to be a control. Consequently, not every widget that you perceive as a control has a native window handle. Inspect.exe does the right thing: It traverses the widget hierarchy querying the [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) providers. That's what you should be using as well.

Comment: May be 'White' can help you: https://github.com/TestStack/White ,
but this is a big problem if you can't catch the handle. You can also try runorex - they are good at recognizing complex controls.

Comment: Also if you just need to automate and not stick to c# , maybe you can do it using 'sikulli' http://www.sikuli.org/

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a screenshot of Inspect results showing both the tree and details panes while selecting the chat box?